# osmdroid shows empty map

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am writing an Android App and want to show an OSM map. I tried the tutorial, but the map is empty all the time.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private IMapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint poin1 = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
        mapController.setCenter(point1);
    }
}
```

I use osmdroid 4.3.

Thanks in advance,
Plebo

Comment: Please post `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: It's strange because your code is correct. Any errors in the logcat?

Comment: Also, you can try osmdroid 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting API23 and running on a 23+ emulator, then you must prompt the user for permissions. See the sample app from v5.1 or newer. You'll also need some kind of local storage for the tile cache.

Comment: Thank you, now it works! The strange thing is that I only need to request the external storage permission on run time, but not the internet permission :D